# Is the set of points in $\mathbb R^n$ with $\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^k = 0$ a submanifold?

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider the set

$$A:= \{x\in \mathbb R^n :\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^k = 0\}$$

for $k$ an odd integer. Is this a submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$ for every $n$? For $n=1$, it is just 0; for $n = 2$, it is the anti-diagonal $\{(x_1 , -x_1) : x_1 \in \mathbb R\}$, which is a submanifold. However, I cannot find a way to determine this in higher dimensions. Any suggestions?

Comment: Preimage by some real function? What can you say about preimages?

Comment: What's the role of $k$ here?  For $k = n = 2$, we have $A = \{(0,0)\}$.

Comment: @Adam:  $k$ is odd.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Thank you.

Comment: Well, typically we can say that a pre-image of a regular value is a submanifold. However, here 0 is not a regular value of $x\mapsto \sum_j x_j^k$ unless $k = 1$.

Comment: @user15464: Remove the origin from your domain, and then $0$ *is* a regular value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your set is scale-invariant: if $x\in A$ and $t\in\mathbb R$ then $tx\in A$. If such a set is a submanifold, then 
[it is a linear subspace](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/180861/53153). If $n>2$, $A$ is not a linear subspace, hence not a manifold.