# Cone is a submanifold iff it is a vector subspace

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, manifolds

Could you tell me how to prove the following?

Let $\emptyset \neq M \subset \mathbb{R}^n $ be a cone ($\forall x \in M, t \in \mathbb{R} : tx \in M $ ), $0 \le d \le n.$

Prove that $M$ is a $d$ -dimensional submanifold class $\mathcal{C}^1 \iff M$ is a $d$ -dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n $.

I will be grateful for all your  help.

Thank you.

Comment: For an idea of where to start, consider what such a cone looks like in $\mathbb{R}^3$: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleCone.html

Comment: For another hint, consider what the charts must look like. Is there a single-chart atlas? Why or why not?

Comment: For yet another hint: think about what happens around 0, and how you can reduce easily to considering a chart around 0 only.

Comment: Thank you.I know that $x^2+y^2=z^2$ is a submanifold only is we assume that $z>0$. It is not a submanifold if we include $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/180861/)